# Speed up carousel on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, carousel

I have a carousel that is moving very slow. I do not know what JS script is controlling the speed and I need it to speed up. Can't get any help form the theme maker. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks

Page:
http://krankgolf2017.wpengine.com/team-krank/

Comment: Also the carousel stops on the third picture. Should go through all of them and loop. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Revolution Slider Plugin`. So if you want to change the settings, go to RevSlider settings and change the speed.

You can read the documentation [here](https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/slider-revolution-jquery-5-x-documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

The carousel is embedded in the site and not visable as a slide in Revo Slider. I found it here:

File Path: \wp-content\themes\porto\content-portfolio-carousel.php

The speed is controlled on line 357 with this code: delay: 4000, I changed it to delay: 100, and that speeded it up.

The amount of slides that rotate through the carousel where stopping at the third slide. I changed it to loop by changing this code on line 545 stopAtSlide: 3, I changed it to this: stopAtSlide: 0, then it looped.

Thanks for your r